# Attached SQL Express DB is causing problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-express

I have been asked to create an MVC web application in VS 2010, and was instructed to use a SQL express database for my data. I am using EF Code-First for creating and managing my data. The database was created in VS2010, and is attached via "AttachDBFilename" in the web.config.

I have used SQL CE before with MVC with no problems, however the attached SQL Express DB is causing weird issues.

For one thing, when I try to deploy the app, it fails and tells me that it cannot copy the database.mdf because it is in use by another process. I have NOT opened the database in VS2010 nor SSMS. Of course the program code accesses it - is there some reason that connection would remain open? I am using boilerplate code from the scaffolding.

I should mention that I use a ProjectInitializer.cs to create the sample data. It runs at every launch for the moment, since I am testing quite a bit.

The other problem I have is that if I delete the database, it fails to recreate it. It says that my windows account does not have access to the (now non-existent) database that it is trying to create. I literally have to create a new database with **new name**, as anything that was created previously (with that DB name) fails.

I assume there is some sort of residual info being left somewhere that is out of synch, but I don't know what it is. I've closed all connections to the file in VS 2010, deleted the files, both any found via VS2010 and any physical files I see in the app_data directory.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is my connectionstring. Should be kosher.     <add name="ProjectContext"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Projekt.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Initial Catalog=Projekt;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 1):

Shut down the web server (Cassini, IIS, IIS Express) and try again. The file can remain locked if the web process is still referencing the file. In addition the loaded EF context will retain the db name. Ensure the visual studio browser isn't running in the tray still either.